# How to remove horizontal scrollBar and make text area with fixed height after using whiteSpace-nowrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, element-ui

I am having text area. I used `white-space: nowrap;` to remove white spaces in text area. but after using this horizontal scrollbar is appearing. So I need to remove horizontal scrollbar and make text area with fixed height.
So is there any way to remove horizontal scrollbar after using white-pace:nowrap
or is there any other way to remove white spaces?

Comment: show some code in your question. `white-space:nowrap;` won't give scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the resizing of the textarea you can use `resize: none`.

To avoid scrollbars you can use `overflow: hidden` or just `overflow-x: hidden` to hide them only horizontally.

Check this fiddle to view these properties in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfuvxvd7/1/